# function return is not what i expect

Tags: javascript, function, append, return

I created a function which parses text and I would like it to return a full link say:

@tw would return `<a href="http://www.twitter.com/tw"></a>`

rather it returns `http://www.twitter.com/tw` with no markup. How can I append the  tag to include the text tw, and return the markup to the html?

```
  String.prototype.parseUsername = function() {
    return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(u) {
        var username = u.replace("@","")
        var twitter_link = document.createElement("a");
        twitter_link.href = "http://www.twitter.com/"+username
        twitter_link.target = "_blank"

        console.log(twitter_link)
        return twitter_link;

    });
  };
```

Comment: How should it deal with multiple mentions? Change the string or return an `Array` of anchors?

Comment: I'm not to good with JavaScript but looks like you have 2 returns maybe one is canceling the other one out.            maybe something like this var str="<a href=\"";    document.write(str.concat(twitter_link,"\"></a>"));            or maybe try return twitter_link.href;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
String.prototype.parseUsername = function(userName) {
    userName = this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, userName.replace("@", ""));
    return (function(u) {
        var twitter_link = document.createElement("a");
        twitter_link.href = "http://www.twitter.com/"+u
        twitter_link.target = "_blank"

        console.log(twitter_link)
        return twitter_link;

    })(userName);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are wanting.

```
String.prototype.parseUsername = function() {
    var links = [];

    this.replace(/@(\w+)/g, function(all, username) {
        var twitter_link = document.createElement("a");
        twitter_link.href = "http://www.twitter.com/" + username;
        twitter_link.target = "_blank"
        links.push(twitter_link);
    });

    return links;
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6bWR/).